# JSON encode to table

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to show JSON array into table,
my db table structure consist: act_id, sales_id, cust_name, act_type, notes, date_add, date_modified, action.

here are the scripts (/api.php):

```
public function get_todo($id = null)
{
    $this->_require_login();   

    if ($id != null){
        $this->db->where([
            'act_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
        ]);
    } else {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    }
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $query = $this->db->get('activity');
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));
}
```

my event.js

```
var load_todo = function() {
    $.get('api/get_todo', function(o){

        var output = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++){
            output += Template.todo(o[i]);
        }

        $("#list_todo").html(output);
    }, 'json');
};
```

this is my template.js

```
output +='<table style="width:80%;">';
    output +='<thead>';
    output += '<tr>';
    output +='<th>' + "Client Name" + '</th>';
    output +='<th>' + "Activity" + '</th>';
    output +='<th>' + "Notes" + '</th>';
    output +='<th>' + "Start" + '</th>';
    output +='<th>' + "Finish" + '</th>';
    output +='<th>' + "Action" + '</th>';
    output +='</tr>';
    output += '</thead>';

    output +='<tbody>';
    output += '<tr>'
    output +='<td>' + obj.cust_name + '</td>';
    output +='<td>' + obj.act_type + '</td>';
    output +='<td>' + obj.act_notes + '</td>';
    output +='<td>' + obj.date_added +'</td>';
    output +='<td>' + obj.date_modified + '</td>';
output += '<td>' + '<a class="todo_update" data-id="' + obj.act_id + '"data-completed="' + data_completed + '" href="api/update_todo">' + data_completed_text + '</a>' + '</td>';
    output += '</tr>';
    output +='</tbody>'; output +='</table>';
```

however it creates duplicate column name in each rows view
[image]

any help would really appreciated. thank you.

Comment: So move header table part out of template. Maybe your templates allow injecting one into another.

Comment: You are probably looping the header every time you are adding a row

Comment: @u_mulder do you mean I put the header table into the view? if I move it out of the template, how to retrieve the data from the event? thanks

Comment: @Llewellyn1411 I guess you're right, but I still can't find any workaround here. any idea?

Comment: You can put it anywhere, even create another template and append it to your html.

Comment: @u_mulder roger that, it's done. I put the table header under the view, with little adjustment it looks alright. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep the header part of the table out of the loop. My advice is to split the program in two halves first, encode the header part, see it's output and then encode the rest of the data and then join as you require.

Comment: I'd like to, but I can't, the site won't let me (don't have enough point or something) :D